# TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот, telebot

Буквально пол месяца назад код работал, ничего не менял, что же это за проблема?
Мой код:

```
baza = ("dd ff", "ss gg", "kk rr")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def keyboard(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == ' Ник ': 
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, random.choice(baza))
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, len(baza))
```

Ошибка:

```
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, random.choice(baza))
File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\random.py", line 347, in choice
    return seq[self._randbelow(len(seq))]
TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()
```

Comment: тут можно сказать только одно, у вас поломанная библиотека ```random```, погуглите как переустановить встроенные библиотеки в ```python3```, либо установите другую версию ```python3```.

Comment: подозреваю, что вы переписали переменную `baza` какой-то функцией перед вызовом `random.choice(baza)`. Попробуйте перед этим вызовом напечатать тип переменной `baza`: `print(type(baza))`

Comment: @zolars Дружище, спасибо за ответ, но это не решение

Comment: @MaxU Да, это оно. Глупая ошибка) Спасибо тебе огромное!